# Create the New Xcode Workspace Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, appdelegate, xcode-workspace

How can i add the one xcode project to already existing xcode project?I want to use the child xcode project files to parent xcode project.Once please give me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to use some files and not the whole project, you can drag in the desired files and make sure not to check 'copy files', so that a reference is dragged into your new project.

If you want to import an entire project, start by dragging it in to your current project. Then click on the current project icon in the top left corner of the IDE, after you have selected the project in the top middle portion of the screen you will see a list of General Capabilities Info etc.  select Build Settings.

Search for 'Header Search Paths' and include a path to the project you are importing. For example if your current project is in /Repos/MyFirstProject/myproj.xcodeProj and your other project is in /Repos/MySecondProject/myotherproj.xcodeproj then the search path would be ../MySecondProject and make it recursive.
Next search for Linker Flags and inside Other Linker Flags add    -all_load -ObjC

This can be tricky and you may need to take some additional steps if you are working with libraries.